# Align buttons evenly on bottom in Android for all screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments

I have a simple view with one image and one bottom navigation bar. I am struggling to fit all buttons for all screen sizes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/simpleImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/icon_left"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_spinner"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Page: " />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/page_dropdown"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="110dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bookmark"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/star_hollow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/icon_right"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_right" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Here] is how it appears in 480 x 800 resolution

[image: Here] is how it appears in 768 x 1280 resolution

[image: Here] is how it appears in 1080 x 1920 resolution

**I need a solution where all of these buttons, controls are evenly distributed on all screen sizes.**

Answer (score 1):

Remove `LinearLayout`, and keep using `RelativeLayout` for the parent layout. use the `layout_below` attribute to place buttons and icons below the image, and use the `layout_toEndOf` attribute to place the component next to the right of other components.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

Answer (score 1):

Don't use RelativeLayout. It's deprecated and should be replaced with `ConstraintLayout`

In `ConstraintLayout` align the outer bottons with the attributes

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" // right side of button
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" // left side of button
```

and the inner ones with

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftButton"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightButton"
```

Find more about [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)